# MySQL licence when developing a website?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I want to create a website in JSP and the database will be MySQL. I will host the website on the internet. Is it required to obtain any licence to develop them on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As http://mysql.com/products/ states, MySQL database has 4 editions.

For development it is enough to use community edition, which is distributed under GPL license, which is open-source license.

You don't need anything.

Answer (score 0):

No it'f free if you don't intend to sell the product including the mysql database software. Found [here](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html).